# Is it undefined behavior to get the address of an array element that is out of bounds?

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

Let's say we allocate a byte array of 10 elements. Accessing any element within bounds is defined.

I understand that reading and writing elements out of bounds is undefined behavior. Is it undefined behavior to get the address of an array element that is out of bounds?

Example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buf[10];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    // Defined behavior
    uint8_t a_value = buf[9];

    // Defined behavior
    buf[0] = 1;

    // Undefined behavior?
    uint8_t *addr = &buf[10];
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`&buf[10]` is a special case. You can get the address of the "one past last element" of an array without UB.  But you can not go further or go before the first element.  Thus `&buf[11]` and `&buf[-1]` is UB.

Per request, from [the latest available draft of C18](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).

6.5.3.2/3 explains that `&buf[10]` is equivalent to `buf+10`:

> Similarly, if the operand is the result of a []
>   operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result
>   is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator.

and 6.5.6/8 gives us information about the behavior of `+`:

> Moreover, if the expression P points to
>   the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array
>   object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression
>   (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point
>   to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation
>   shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Actually, 6.5.3.2p3 is also needed to get the conversion from `&buf[10]` to `buf + 10`: *The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type "type",
the result has type "pointer to type". If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator,
neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue*

Answer (score -4):

No getting the reference without dereferencing or using it any other way (with some exceptions) is not the Undefined Behaviour.

An example:

```
int x[5];

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*(x + 1000));   // no UB
```

Comment: Actually, this one special case is OK, being the address of the first item after the array.

Comment: Yes, but the answer should state that. Currently it sounds that it is the general case which is not correct.

Comment: @EugeneSh. getting the reference without any pointer operations and dereferencing is not the UB.

Comment: @P__J__: Standard C provides no defined way to calculate the reference. C 2018 6.5.6 8 says, of using `+` with pointers: “If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: However, in `sizeof(*(x + 1000)`, the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated, so no undefined behavior occurs. The result is merely the size of the **type** of the expression. If `x + 1000` were evaluated, the C standard would not define the behavior. E.g., the behavior of the expression statement `x + 1000;` is not defined by the C standard, even though its result is not used.

Comment: One reason for this feature of the C standard is that some C implementations have to use supplemental data to manage memory, so a pointer is not merely an address of an object. It includes other data structures, and calculating pointer arithmetic might involve looking things up in those structures, and a lookup with an invalid index might step off into unmapped memory or otherwise bollux the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this discussion is pointless. IMO you over interpret the standard. I do not know any implementation or machine where pointer arithmetic may lead the effects described in the comment. It is even very hard to imagine this kind of weird implementation.

Comment: The C standard is quite clear; it explicitly states, in the quote I provided “the behavior is undefined.” The statement “I do not know any implementation or machine…” is merely a statement of your lack of knowledge, not information or reasoning useful for interpreting the C standard. I do know of machines where supplemental data structures had to be used to manage objects in memory. Furthermore, Clang has become more aggressive about pointer provenance, so that pointer arithmetic not defined by the C standard may break even if the target implementation has a flat address space.

Comment: @P__J__, the good old 80286.  Loading an invalid segment in a segment register results in an interrupt, segments are limited to 64K in size.  There have been, at least it was part of the folklore in the 90, I've not used them, implementations which allowed objects bigger than 64K by allowing contiguous segments and thus doing pointer arithmetic in such a way that pointers went outside allocated segments could generate invalid segments, leading to crashes.  There are also descriptor based processor for which going out of bound is trapped (although I don't know if any has a C compiler).

Comment: `Loading an invalid segment in a segment register` There is no loading as there is dereferencing or using.  So to **calculate** the reference the compiler will change  any egment registers? If yes,  change the compiler